# How many curves fit at the plane?

Tags: set-theory

I have read an article of scientific dissemination about transfinite numbers where there are not many details and it is said that the set of all curves that one can draw in a plane has cardinality alef 2. Someone know what does the author means with curves that can be drawn and on what result is based?

Comment: This is not correct without additional assumptions, though I presume the issue is simply that you are using  the notation $\aleph_2$ inaccurately. Anyway, please clarify the meaning of the terms you are using. Are curves continuous? What is their domain? Is the fact that they can be drawn meant to indicate that they are further assumed to be rectifiable?

Comment: The article FROM ZERO TO ALEF-ZERO is of scientific dissemination, so the author do not give all the details. However the author, named Joaquin Navarro, wants to give us an example of a set whose cardinality is alef 2, this is the set given above. I would like to clear what does he meant with the set of all the curves that can be drawn and why the cardinality is alef 2.

Comment: Do you happen to have more detailed bibliographic data or a link to the publication with those claims?

Comment: @Martin Sleziak: Not really, I found this article  on some spanish encyclopedia by editorial Salvat editores. I believe that it is difficult to find it, but if you want I can send you the article scanned.

Comment: @DIEGOR. I do not need the article, I am mainly asking because this would be one of the possibilities how to clarify and improve the question. You perhaps did not notice this yet, but your post [received several close votes](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/858331), the users who voted to close chose the close reason "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: @Martin Sleziak: Ah ok thanks. I described the example given such as it is written in the article. The importan is that the pleople who answer to me helped to make sense to all this.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: Even if you're satisfied with the answers, it might be good to edit - IIRC many closed questions increase probability of getting into [question bat](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/post-ban/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably what is meant by curves in the plane in this context is functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R.$

The cardinality of that set is $\large 2^{2^{\large\aleph_0}}.$

**If** $2^{\aleph_0}= \aleph_1$ and **if** $2^{\aleph_1} = \aleph_2,$ then  this cardinality would be $\aleph_2.$ But many mathematicians who haven't studied these things are confused about conventional definitions and think that the definition of $\aleph_{k+1}$ is $2^{\aleph_k}.$ That is wrong. The standard usage going back to Cantor himself is that $\aleph_1$ is the cardinality of the set of all countable ordinals, and $\aleph_2$ is the cardinality of the set of all ordinals of cardinality $\aleph_1.$ Cantor conjectured that $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$ and could not prove it. It was later shown that the conventional axioms of set theory do not contain sufficient information to determine whether $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1.$

Comment: Now all this makes sense for me.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably "curves that one can draw" implies that these are Borel sets.  Assuming the Axiom of Choice, the set of Borel subsets of the plane has cardinality $\frak c$.  The continuum hypothesis would imply this is $\aleph_1$.  It is also consistent with ZFC to assume that it is $\aleph_n$, where $n$ is any positive integer.